# how to reduce Image width and height in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project where have to display the images by using image path.
For this I write one method taking the image path as an argument.

My goal is to reduce the size of image(width and height)

Comment: Do you want to change the image display area, or you want to change the size of actual image and save it? what is your exact requirement?

Comment: What have you tried? @editor: stop formatting 'interesting' words as `inline code`, that doesn't quite increase readability.

Comment: Oops,First Google If not Solutoion Founded Reffer to Stack !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the image into an instance of the [WebImage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) you can do those things simply using the `Resize` method.

```
var webImage = new WebImage(image);
webImage.Resize(200, 200, false, true);
webImage.Save("~/path", "png", true);
```

In the example, `image` passed into the `WebImage` as a param could be  a `byte[]` for the file or just a `string` path to the file. I set the image dimensions to 200*200 and saved it as a PNG.

Comment: Do you want a resize operation to run each time an image is requested?

Comment: I'm just showing an example of usage. personally I would use this on upload or in a pre-processing manner so future requests show the resized image. It could be used for displaying directly on each request using `Write` rather than `save`. I linked the MSDN doc to show the classes abilities as there are quite a few.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [image resampling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET).

Here's a VERY quick and dirty way of resampling an image in C#.NET using Bilinear interpolation.

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = Bitmap.FromFile("path_to_file");
Bitmap bmpResampled = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpResampled);
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bilinear;
g.DrawImage(bmpOriginal, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpResampled.Width + 1, bmpResampled.Height + 1));
```

Your resampled version will now be contained in `bmpResampled`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to edit width and height without any complications and changing the actual size.

This is pure html way.

```
<img id="" src ="Your image path" height ="100" width = "100"></img>
```

or you can use an asp control

```
<asp:Image ID ="img" runat ="server" ImageUrl = "your path"  Width ="100" Height ="100"/>
```

that is if your problem is this simple. Just put height and width values accordingly.

Comment: I would avoid this way. If you have a 5mb file, forcing it down to 100*100 wont fix that file size. It also does not do anything to maintain image proportions.

Comment: Of course but I highly doubt his issue is that complicated, I believe he retrieves a large image from a source and it's probably just too big for the screen or a specific div.